# While executing GC program i am getting NPE error, can anyone correct me please?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

package com.java.gc;

public class FinalizeDemo 
{
    static FinalizeDemo s;

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
{
    FinalizeDemo f = new FinalizeDemo();
    System.out.println("f hashcode:" +f.hashCode());
    f=null;
    System.gc();
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    System.out.println("s hashcode:"+s.hashCode());
    s=null;
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    System.out.println("ENd of main");

}
public void finlaize()
{
    System.out.println("Finlaize method called");
    s=this;
}
```

}

Getting NPE while runnig this code , can anyone please help me?

Comment: What do you intend to achieve with this code? It looks kind of unstructured.

Comment: Even if this wouldn't be another duplicate of that question... Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Don't just throw some code at us and "not working". It is absolutely unclear what this code is supposed to do or result in.

Comment: You have a typo in `finlaize` should be `finalize`. Be aware though that `finalize` is deprecated starting with java 9.